# Why do R packages using C++ use #include <R.h>, #include <Rdefines.h> and #include <Rmath.h>?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am working on a massive R package with a lot of old C++ files in it. Only one function is called by `.Call` in R.
At the beginning there is a lot a `#include` call, that I'm removing by commenting and compiling, but one thing I don't understand is the difference between:

- #include <R.h>
- #include <Rdefines.h>
- #include <Rmath.h>

I want to clean this part of every files to remove useless libraries, but in most [examples](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/07/using-r-callhello-2/) I see, there is both `R.h` and `Rdefines.h`, although commenting `R.h` return no warnings during the compilation. Is it usefull ?

PS : The final objective is to only use Rcpp, but for now I first need to understand and clean the project.

Comment: The include directives mean that these header files are included (effectively the whole header file is copy-pasted in place of the directive). The three different header files that are included are definitely different files with different definitions and macros in them. It is possible that one or more of them was included unnecessarily when the file was written, but it's impossible to say from the information you have provided. If you are using `#include<Rcpp.h>` then all three of these header files are already #included anyway, so can be taken out. Maybe that's why it still compiles?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, it bother me too ^^' I understand it's different files, but using `#include<Rcpp.h>` don't replace the 3 above, the compiler don't find the functions used (example : `rnom`).

Comment: Sorry @Gowachin - Rcpp.h #includes Rcppcommon.h, which #incudes Rcpp/r/headers.h, which #includes R.h. I don't think it includes Rdefines.h or Rmath.h. If you are using Rcpp, you can certainly get rid of R.h. I thought the other two were ultimately #included too, but perhaps not.

Comment: Good to know ! Unfortunelty there is conflict in function names between `Rdefines.h` or `Rmath.h` and `Rcpp.h`, `length()` for example. I guess I will maintain `Rdefines.h` until the 21k lines of C++ code are upgraded to `Rcpp`.

Comment: @Gowachin:  The "conflict" is resolved when you declare R_NO_REMAP which Rcpp does, and preferably also STRICT_R_HEADERS which we recommend -- and will set in the next version.  In short, there never was an issue, it is all documented too.  As everybody told you here, if _you_ program with Rcpp, just use the one `#include <Rcpp.h>` and all is well.

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel ! The issue with this project is too migrate from SEXP style to Rcpp, with somekind of hybrid system during the process. If you have some examples or documentation about this, I will be happy to take a look at it !